# Unable to deploy firebase cloud functions to any firebase project from my machine (but it works perfectly fine on my colleague's machine)

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

[image: Mac-mini configuration]

This is my mac-mini M1 configuration and I'm trying to deploy firebase functions but it is not allowing me to deploy and every time shows me this error.

When I run this command it throws an error :

```
me@-Mac-mini demo % firebase deploy --only functions:helloWorld



=== Deploying to 'demo'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> tsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /Users/me/Documents/work/workspace/demo/functions (56.87 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
⚠  functions: failed to create function projects/demo/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld
Failed to create function projects/demo/locations/us-central1/functions/helloWorld

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        helloWorld(us-central1)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/artifacts/docker/demo/us-central1/gcf-artifacts

Error: There was an error deploying functions
```

The actual log of the error :

```
{"@type":"type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog","status":{"code":7,"message":"Cloud Functions uses Artifact Registry to store function docker images. Artifact Registry API is not enabled in your project. To enable the API, use the gcloud command 'gcloud services enable artifactregistry.googleapis.com' then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."}
```

Other versions info :

```
   NPM version : 8.11.0
   Firebase version : 11.2.0
   Node version : 16.15.1
```

Firebase package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "16"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^10.2.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.21.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Deploying from MacBook-pro-2014
[image: Deploying from MacBook-pro-2014]
Deploying from Mac-mini-m1
[image: Deploying from Mac-mini-m1]

**Why I am unable to deploy cloud functions from my machine and why is my colleague able to deploy the same cloud functions to same Firebase project from his machine even without enabling Artifacts Registry?**

Answer (score 2):

The Artifact Registry API is not enabled in your project.

The solution requires that billing is enabled for your project.

Provided that the CLI has permission to enable services, run this command:

```
gcloud services enable artifactregistry.googleapis.com
```

Or use the [Google Cloud Console UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=artifactregistry.googleapis.com)

More information is available in the Artifact Registry Documentation:

- [Enabling and disabling the service](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/enable-service)
- [Artifact Registry pricing](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/pricing)

Comment: So why i am able to deploy the same cloud function to the same project from other machines without enabling this Artifact Registry service?

Comment: @KevalTank - You can't be. The error is very clear **Artifact Registry API is not enabled in your project.** Did you actually check if the API is enabled? I provided you links, did you follow them?

Comment: Does anyone know where it is stated that Artifact Registry API is always required to deploy (Google Cloud) Firebase Functions? It never was before and the getting started tutorials do not mention it. Artifact Registry seems option but recommended the way it is described. I have the same error with updating one of my functions and do not want to enable an API without being sure I know what I'm getting in to :)

Comment: @john Thanks for your help and guidance and Yes, I've checked that link. But the thing is we are able to deploy the same cloud functions in the same Firebase project (without enabling the API) on a different machine then why it's not working on my machine?
Please check out the question I've updated with more details and attachments.

Comment: @KevalTank What is the problem with enabling the API? Do you not have billing enabled? Your other applications might be using Container Registry. Double-check to be sure.

Comment: @KevalTank The Firebase CLI creates a .zip archive of the function code, which is then uploaded to a Cloud Storage bucket (prefixed with gcf-sources) before Cloud Functions creates an Artifact Registry repository (named gcf-artifacts) in your project.
Cloud Build retrieves the function code and builds the function source. You can view Cloud Build logs in the Google Cloud Console.
The container image for the built functions code is uploaded to a private Artifact Registry repository in your project (named gcf-artifacts), and your new function is rolled out. So this is the reason.

Comment: Actually, My question is **Why I am unable to deploy cloud functions from my machine and why is my colleague able to deploy the same cloud functions to same Firebase project from his machine even without enabling Artifacts Registry?** cc: @PriyashreeBhadra

Comment: @KevalTank - If Artifact Registry is not enabled, your colleague is not deploying the same Cloud function using Artifact Registry. Edit your question and show the logs and command output of your colleague deploying successfully. YOu need two items enabled: 1) Billing; 2) Artifact Registry. Edit your question with details on if Billing is enabled.